# What does "was not happening" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

9Post Scriptum:

The album called Debris Vol. II was not happening, but instead of it, Everything is Temporary was released in 1999

Does "was not happening" mean there had been a hope that the album would be out but now it was over or does it mean at that time when she was writing  there was still a hope but yet nothing had seen the light of the day.
I would say the latter  must be the good one because if they had been no hope the writer would have written "did not happen"

https://talesfromthebraziersgrotto.wordpress.com/2022/11/06/everything-is-temporary-epic-soundtracks-23-3-1959-6-11-1997/?fbclid=IwAR34UzXzyw5fhAPpapFd2XVuhXuFDNR6mdONyrLHlFDCeQ_Fz2pL7R

Answer (score 1):

Casually, to say that something is "not happening" means that it isn't developing or progressing as hoped. It suggests that the speaker had expected the album to be progressing, and believed that everything was prepared, but for reasons that aren't clear to the speaker, no progress was made.

> The album just wasn't happening. I'd got the band together with a great producer, but when we sat down to play we just argued about trivial things and nothing got recorded.